# Why does this image look so bad after being scaled down in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing, graphics2d

Here is the original image: http://rank.my/public/images/uploaded/orig-4193395691714613396.png

And here it is scaled down to 300x225:

http://rank.my/public/images/uploaded/norm-4193395691714613396.png

And here it is scaled down to 150x112:

http://rank.my/public/images/uploaded/small-4193395691714613396.png

As you can see, 300x225 looks pretty bad, and 150x112 looks awful.  Here is the code I'm using to scale down the image:

```
private static BufferedImage createResizedCopy(final BufferedImage source, final int destWidth,
        final int destHeight) {
    final BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(destWidth, destHeight, source.getType());
    final Graphics2D bg = resized.createGraphics();
    bg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    bg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    bg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    final float sx = (float) destWidth / source.getWidth();
    final float sy = (float) destHeight / source.getHeight();
    bg.scale(sx, sy);
    bg.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
    bg.dispose();
    return resized;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  The image scaling doesn't have to be especially fast, quality is definitely a priority over speed.  Am I using the wrong technique?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I think your deleted answer is excellent, and I wish you'd undelete it.

Comment: Links are dead, please host with imgur or similar :)

Comment: Links are back up now - sorry

Comment: Dead links again. Please just add them directly to the post, or use imgur. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to fix the downscaling problem. First is to do it in multiple steps, with no more than a 75% reduction in each step. The second is to blur the image before resizing; the more it shrinks, the more you'll have to blur. The third way is to use a method that filters using more than the 2x2 to 4x4 pixel blocks used by a naive bilinear or bicubic interpolation method. As the shrink factor grows larger, so should the pixel block used by the filter, otherwise you get aliasing artifacts as you've seen here.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used these libraries so I feel unqualified to answer, but I can't help but pass along these links I found that I think may be useful. Hopefully this will help.

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

http://www.componenthouse.com/article-20

Comment: The today.java.net link looks pretty good to me, especially the section titled "Creating scaled instances" and the sample `getScaledInstance(...)` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

JAI is pretty frustrating. I still wonder why, no matter what settings you do, it never matches the speed, quality and simplicity of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). I prefer to use ImageMagick wherever I can.

The code below is what gives me best result for image scaling. Please note that I have used `RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY` and `SubsampleAverage` and *not* `RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC`.

I have wrapped up JAI processing in a small block and always use it to scale down. The same code *does not* give good result when you scale-up -- a different setting applies for that. I have not tried with PNG, JPEG is what I worked with.

Hope this helps

```
//Set-up and load file
PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", absPath);
RenderingHints quality = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
p.put("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", "true");
System.setProperties(p);

//Setup the processes
ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock()
    .addSource(image)
    .add(scaleX)     //scaleX = (double)1.0*finalX/origX
    .add(scaleY);    //scaleY = (double)1.0*finalY/origY
RenderedOp tempProcessingFile = JAI.create("SubsampleAverage", pb, quality);

//Save the file
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
JPEGEncodeParam encodeParam = new JPEGEncodeParam();
encodeParam.setQuality(0.92f); //My experience is anything below 0.92f gives bad result
ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("JPEG", fout, encodeParam);
encoder.encode(tempProcessingFile.getAsBufferedImage());
```

Also, the articles that helped me are.

- https://jaistuff.dev.java.net/docs/jaitutorial.pdf
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html
- <strike>http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5332078</strike> Looks like after Oracle acquisition they have washed away the forum posts. This was an extra-ordinary discussion over JAI performance and quality. I still had it bookmarked.
- http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/how-to-resize-uploaded-images-using-java-better-way.html

(The links above are from my bookmark, edit them if you find they are dead)

Comment: I believe SubsampleAverage follows my third suggestion, using a larger pixel block of input for each pixel output.

Comment: that lost link to Sun forums, could it be this one: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1270119? This thread starts with _"It seems to be the easiest thing to do in JAI (or any image API for that matter) but gives me a headache. Task is: scale down an image with best quality. Outcome: JAI has poor performance compared to standard applications like GIMP..."_ Then it goes on with `RenderingHints KEY_RENDERING, VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY` and with `MemoryCacheSeekableStream` and ends with suggestion to use `ImageReadParam setSourceRegion, setSourceSubsampling`