# Best way to reduce aliasing artifacts in open gl es? (Image re-sizing)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, image-resizing

Ok, so whenever I scale an image down I get some aliasing artifacts. Really don't want that.

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964979/why-does-this-image-look-so-bad-after-being-scaled-down-in-java) and saw what he recommend, but not sure how that would apply to open gl.

I know that open gl pretty much automatically scales it. However, what should I look at doing that would make the image look nice?

Should I scale inside of GL or outside? Would you recommend scaling before I even create the texture?

Really would like to see what is standard for this. Thanks!

If complicated, please include some example code... even if just pseudo code.

Comment: antialiasing is aided by a variety of techniques. one option is to use textures mipmapped onto your meshes for the lines, thus these textures could be antialiased already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term you should look for is multisampling with opengl-es 2.0.  You should turn that on to get smoother scaling in your rendering.

- [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388176/793607) to a similar question.
- [Here is a link to a document](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/05/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-33/#multisampling) that contains a great explanation of multisampling in opengles and some nice pictures.

For 1.0 you could use [the complex answer here.](http://www.saschahlusiak.de/2012/10/opengl-antialiasing-in-android-with-transparent-textures/)

- [Here is a nice link to a sample app that shows how to do Multisampling on Android.](http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/)

Some source:

```
// Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    if (kUseMultisampling)
        setEGLConfigChooser(mConfigChooser = new MultisampleConfigChooser());
    setRenderer(mRenderer = new GDC11Renderer());
```

Comment: Do I have to use open-gl es 2.0 in order for that to work? Or will open-gl es 1.0 or 1.1 work? I am trying to support as many devices as possible.

Comment: I put a link up that works for open-gl es 1.0 or 1.1.  You can't use the same technique for both types of openGl, as that is one of the main differences between the two opengl's

Comment: Actually I am going to switch to OpenGL ES 2.0. Anyways, I don't get how you even begin to enable or use MSAA in android. The example of multisampling above uses plugins for Apples iOS. So they are not on android and was hoping for another answer. The similar question uses GL10 which is not GLES20. Also was reading OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide by Munshim Ginsburg, and shreiner. It talked about using GLES20.glSampleCoverage(float, boolean) for sampling. However, I could not find out more on what they were trying to say.

Comment: I put a link to a nice sample app that shows how to do it in 2.0 on the android.

Comment: Ok, looking over it now. Probably will be playing with it for a bit. Have a quick question though, is multi-sampling set through gl or egl? Why?

Comment: EGL.  I posted a snippet.

Comment: And this turns on multisampling for textures, lines, triangles, ect... cool. Thanks so much! Still have to get this working, but helpful!

Comment: Multisampling takes an additional pass over your entire view.  It is expensive (relatively) for performance, but is really a much more modern approach to cleaning things up, and hence is more like what you see in more advanced graphics.